# is there a jquery gallery plugin with the following features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I'm Looking for a jQuery gallery plugin

for example when i click an image i will see 4 other images (beside the ones in

index)

wich mean if i have 4 images in index , when i click an image i will see 4 other

images (hidden untill i click their home image)

i hope this is clear,

thank you ; 
PS: i already searched for that but i didn't find anything

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: create one for yourself, share any problem that you face while developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.image',function(){ 
var index = jQuery('.image').index(this);
 jQuery('.image:eq(index)').show(); 
jQuery('.image').not(":eq(index)").hide();
 });
```